# Can't get EXPORT AS DEFAULT to work on chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, module, ecmascript-6, transcrypt

I am investigating adding ES6 import/export to the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) Python to JavaScript compiler.
As an experiment to that end I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />            
        <script type="module" src="testmodule.js"></script> 
        <script type="module" src="testmain.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and testmodule.js:

```
'use strict';

function testmodule_f () {
    function cube(x) {
      return x * x * x;
    }
    const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
    var graph = {
        options:{
            color:'white',
            thickness:'2px'
        },
        draw: function(){
            console.log('From graph draw function');
        }
    }
    var all = {cube, foo, graph};
    return all;
}

var testmodule = testmodule_f ();

export {testmodule as default};
```

and testmain.js:

```
'use strict';

import {tm} from './testmodule.js';
tm.graph.options = {
    color:'blue',
    thickness:'3px'
}; 
tm.graph.draw();
console.log(tm.cube(3)); // 27
console.log(tm.foo);    // 4.555806215962888
```

I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'tm'
```

With normal named export (so no default) it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Also if I change testmain.js to the following it works:

```
'use strict';
import {default as tm} from './testmodule.js';
tm.graph.options = {
    color:'blue',
    thickness:'3px'
}; 
tm.graph.draw();
console.log(tm.cube(3)); // 27
console.log(tm.foo);    // 4.555806215962888
```

Seems Chrome doesn't do anything with the word `default`, other than treating it like a perfectly ordinary name? But that contradicts:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Have you tried `export default { testmodule };`?

Comment: Yes, see solution below...

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

testmain.js

```
'use strict';
import tm from './testmodule.js';
tm.graph.options = {
    color:'blue',
    thickness:'3px'
}; 
tm.graph.draw();
console.log(tm.cube(3)); // 27
console.log(tm.foo);    // 4.555806215962888
```

testmodule.js

```
'use strict';

function testmodule_f () {
    function cube(x) {
      return x * x * x;
    }
    const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
    var graph = {
        options:{
            color:'white',
            thickness:'2px'
        },
        draw: function(){
            console.log('From graph draw function');
        }
    }
    var all = {cube, foo, graph};
    return all;
}

var testmodule = testmodule_f ();

export default testmodule;
```

Still I'm under the impression that the original code should also work...

Comment: That's gotta sting. Does it feel unjust?

Comment: Actually  could have saved me some experimenting time if it had been documented somewhere ;)